# Redirect Url in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this URL: `http://localhost:1356/MyProfile/Login.aspx`

I want to redirect this to `http://localhost:1356`
How to with javascript?

Comment: location.href = ....

Comment: Please use the search.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
window.location.href = 'http://localhost:1356';
```